# Array Formula using Large Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, formula

Im trying to calculate an array formula based on the top values, Say the top 20% and find the cut off

At the moment my formula is similar to {=max(row(1:7)*--(sum(large(indirect(range),row(1:7))))

to find the maximum value that doesnt fit the formula, ie (1,2,3,0,0,0) then the max picks up the 3

Can someone give me some pointers on where im going wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

With this data in A1:A10

```
10
8
5
6
4
2
3
1
9
7
```

Sum everything in the top 20% (19)

```
=SUM((A1:A10>PERCENTILE(A1:A10,0.8))*(A1:A10))
```

Find the largest number in bottom 80% (8)

```
=MAX((A1:A10<=PERCENTILE(A1:A10,0.8))*(A1:A10))
```

Find the smallest number in the top 20% (9)

```
=MIN(IF(A1:A10>PERCENTILE(A1:A10,0.8),(A1:A10),""))
```

Comment: Neat that's probably the way to go. I was assuming from the appearance of `sum` inside the `max` formula that the top 20% was relative to the entire population (55 in this case). We'll have to see what the correct interpretation is...

Comment: Yeah thats awesome, I was just after the one value Thanks alot !

Comment: After testing some more, its not 100% what i wanted, if a1:a10 has 3 numbers between 5 and 10, 2 numbers between 1 and 3 and the rest between 0 and 1 it doesnt give 20% of the total value, it gives 20% of the top 4 values in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are wanting for `sum(large(indirect(range),row(1:7)))` to return an array of cumulative values starting from largest to smallest? You could try instead in your array formula:

```
MMULT(--(ROW(1:7)>=TRANSPOSE(ROW(1:7))),LARGE(A1:A7,ROW(1:7)))
```

and test if this sum is greater than 20% of the total.